# How to perform clustering on this list of data?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis

My knowledge of clustering analysis and data science is superficial. My problem is to group the following data into clusters:

```
Data = [40,45,50,60]
```

My criteria is to group the numbers when the difference between each pair of numbers is within a certain threshold (let's say 10). So the possible clusters are:

```
Cluster1 = [40,45] [50,60]
Cluster2 = [40,45,50] [60]
Cluster3 = [40][45,50][60]
```

I need to find all such possible clusters and select one of them based on a certain condition. Is there any data science library which I can use to perform such clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is one dimensional, the problem becomes *much* easier than the usual clustering scenario which is multivariate.

You can use a very simple strategy to enumerate all possible "clusterings":

1. Sort your data
2. Begin with the smallest value
3. If the next value is within the threshold add it to the cluster and continue
4. Backtrack, and try without adding the value to the existing cluster, but rather begin a new cluster.

**Stop looking for a library for everything**, and just *code* this yourself. Clustering libraries solve more complicated problems and will usually not include such simple univariate strategies.

Answer (score 1):

There are abundant clustering libraries, **BUT** you cant close your eyes and pick one, because if you do so then the entire analysis is flawed.

You have to ask yourself the question, "why are you clustering?", is it to reduce the dimensionality or to find patterns. Another question, you need to ask is, `how are the different variables related to each other?`

The data that you showed above `looks numerical`. For grouping numerical data, you can use the simplest algorithm [k-means](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-k-means-clustering-in-machine-learning-6a6e67336aa1?gi=d69ddf3738fa). `looks numerical` mean is it really numerical values or dummy coded to represent text values.

Another important question in clustering is to determine and prove the presence of `x` number of groups. The `k-means` algorithm is a partitional method and it requires the input of `possible number of clusters`.

Overall, I recommend that you need to rethink this feasibility of this question and answer the questions asked to derive a meaningful solution to your problem.